# Help with htaccess redirect rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I want to use Helicon ISAPI Rewrite to redirect an old URL to a new URL, **but only within a virtual directory** named colors:

http://www.**mydomain.com**/colors/default.aspx?id=blue

needs to redirect to

http://www.**newdomain.org**/colors/default.aspx?id=blue

I am new to this and cannot find an appropriate example, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another possibility:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(colors/.*)$ http://www.newdomain.org/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Helicon ISAPI Rewrite appears to share mod_rewrite's syntax, so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_URL} ^/colors
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.org/$1 [R]
```